# Limit doubletap gesture to just one double tap

Tags: android, animation, gesture

I have this `onDoubleTap` method implemented, it is really simple, it just pops up a photo, what I like is that if I do the `doubleTap` it just animate it one time and when I do it again it dosn't do it anymore

Here is my code

```
@Override
public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    animateHeart(myImageView);
    return false;
}

public void animateHeart(final ImageView view) {
    ScaleAnimation scaleAnimation = new ScaleAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
            prepareAnimation(scaleAnimation);

    AlphaAnimation alphaAnimation = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 3.0f);
    prepareAnimation(alphaAnimation);

    AnimationSet animation = new AnimationSet(true);
    animation.addAnimation(alphaAnimation);
    animation.addAnimation(scaleAnimation);
    animation.setDuration(400);
    animation.setFillAfter(true);

    view.startAnimation(animation);    
}

private Animation prepareAnimation(Animation animation){
    animation.setRepeatCount(1);
    animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE);
    return animation;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to return `true` if the event is consumed. Then, why don't you have a flag to check if you already handled it?

```
private boolean isConsumed;

@Override
public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    if (!isConsumed) {
        animateHeart(myImageView);
        isConsumed = true;
    }
    return true;
}
```